# Populate multiples DropDownList using an array

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I try to populate severals DropDownLists. In my UI there are multiples tabs and always the same DropDownList in each tab. I use an array then a foreach to populate my DropDownList like that :

```
public void DropDownList()
    { 
        string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Datas.xml");
        using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
        {
            DropDownList[] ddls = new DropDownList[]{
               DropDownList_1, DropDownList2,
               DropDownList4, DropDownList5,
               DropDownList7
            };

            foreach (DropDownList ddl in ddls)
            {
                ds.ReadXml(filePath);
                ddl.DataSource = ds;
                ddl.DataTextField =  "name";
                ddl.DataValueField = "id";
                ddl.DataBind();
            }        
        }
    }
```

Here is the XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <fields>
      <cafs>
        <caf>
          <id>1</id>
          <name>TEST18</name>
        </caf>
        <caf>
          <id>2</id>
          <name>TEST28</name>
        </caf>
        <caf>
          <id>3</id>
          <name>TEST36</name>
        </caf>
        <caf>
          <id>4</id>
          <name>TEST45</name>
        </caf>
        <caf>
          <id>5</id>
          <name>TOTAL</name>
        </caf>
      </cafs>  
    </fields>
```

Image of the error : [image]

But I get an error on the `line ddl.DataBind();`

it says that `System.Data.DataRowView have no 'name' property.` (null in InnerException)

I don't understand why because it was working before. The dataset is loaded and I can display it in Visualizer.

Any ideas why this error could occur ?

Comment: can you please post sample of your XML file?

Comment: You'll need to show your `Datas.xml` file contents.

Comment: Error is pretty self-explanatory. Your data set does not have a `name` property/column anymore. Have you changed it recently?

Comment: I put my XML and a picture of the error

Comment: @Julien698, note how exactly you are reading the xml. The `cafs` list is not the top-most element, it is wrapped into `fields`. So what happens is most likely that the whole `cafs` list is getting bound as a single item. Try to debug and go throught the dataset structure to see what I mean. Also try removing `fields` tags from the xml file, it will most likely make the issue go away

Comment: @Andrei Thanks for your help, it works whithout the `fields` tags it is a good thing. I remenber I recently modify the XML in the aim to Add more fields `<cafs>` and `<infos>`  which are wrapped into `fields`. According to you it is possible to put others elements to have only one XML for other DropDownList ?

Comment: @Julien698, yes, you can absolutely reuse the same xml, but now you have to bind your data bound controls to only parts of it. Consider using linq-to-xml, may make your life reading the document a bit easier

Comment: ok, I'll try that later thanks for your help